# Open a Ringtone Picker to select Notification sound in iOS (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, ringtone

I'm not able to choose a ringtone from the default ones on iOS and possibly play it later. At the moment I can do it with a BundleResource but give the user the chance to choose a ringtone would be apprecieted. Is it possible? In Android I achieve it with something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ActionRingtonePicker);
intent.PutExtra(RingtoneManager.ExtraRingtoneTitle, 
AppnameMobile.Resources.AppResources.SelectRingtoneMessages);
intent.PutExtra(RingtoneManager.ExtraRingtoneShowSilent, false);

Context.StartActivityForResult(intent, 77);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately iOS does not allow you to access their  ringtones on the phone. You must import your own ringtones into the application for iOS. Here is a [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsound) that explains the formatting for doing so.

It is for a notification sound but I imagine if you wanted to use the sound for other purposes the importing method is the same.